# Can additional colours be added to Branding Sets?

Tags: experience-cloud, experience-builder-page, theme-branding, audience, custom-theme-layout

Can Branding Sets be extended to add additional colour options?

I have a custom Aura theme layout, and added some design attributes (`<design:attribute>`), but as far as I know, they can't be set per Branding Set.

Failing that, is there any way to add specific CSS to an Experience Cloud site based on the Branding Set or Audience?